# Python search for hyphenated words with re.search

Tags: python, python-re, pypdf

i'm trying to do a search in a PDF using PyPDF and return the page number the search term was found on using re.search.  However, when the word has a hyphen in it, it doesn't work.  For example, search for "abc-123" returns nothing.  I tried the below code and it works for a search of "123" or "abc" but will not return "abc-123".  Below is my code, which is from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571905/finding-on-which-page-a-search-string-is-located-in-a-pdf-document-using-python).

```
# Open the pdf file
pdfFileObj = open('example.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
    
String = 'abc-123'

# Extract text and do the search
for i in range(0, NumPages):
    PageObj = pdfReader.getPage(i)
    Text = PageObj.extractText()
    if re.search(String,Text):
        print("Pattern Found on Page: " + str(i))
        pdfFileObj.close()
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is in Text when you're expecting a match? If you test this with Python repr you'll see it works: `re.search('abc-123', 'cat+abc-123+dog')`

Comment: Possible the '-' in PDF is a graphical hyphen not ASCII code 45 (-). Try searching for "abc.123"

Comment: jarmod - the Text is the text from a page of the PDF document (it's a mostly text (ASCII) document).   For example the document has a line that is "ABC-02177 and ABC-01893" and when i search "ABC-01893" it doesn't return a hit.  JasonM1 - If i search it for "abc-123" using any pdf viewer (sumatra, acorbat)  it finds it, but it doesn't with the above code.

Comment: hey JasonM1, i think it may be the hyphen.  but the "abc.123" doesn't work.,  How do i use the re.DOTALL in the search line?

Answer (score 0):

`re.search` looks for a pattern in a given string.  Assuming the document is returned as a collection of strings or with newlines means that it won't search past the first line.  Try `findall` instead and then take the first match.

```
...
matches = re.findall(String,Text)
if len(matches) > 0:
    print('Found a match ...')
else:
    print('No match found.')
...
```